# I'm learning Ruby and using Watir to create a coupon clipping project. I'm having trouble looping through the process though

Tags: ruby, watir

I'm trying to write a script in Ruby that will automatically clip coupons on a webpage for me. This page being:
[Stop and Shop Coupons Page](https://stopandshop.com/dashboard/coupons-deals/#/coupons-and-deals/exclusive-coupons)

What I have so far will open the browser (Firefox) and go to the coupons page on my account, but will only click one coupon and then the script closes. I've tried while loops, I've tried exists? and everything I could find online and I can't get it to clip continuously for all instances of the button '+ load to card'.

I wrote a script for the Publix website a while ago using the site:
[Publix Coupon Page](https://www.publix.com/savings/coupons/digital-coupons)
and it worked just fine. To "clip" I just used:

```
b.buttons(:class => 'dc-clip-btn').each do |b|
    b.click
    sleep 2
end
```

I needed the "sleep" because sometimes the page would hang on the clip and the script would close. When I tried this same on the Stop & Shop page, it didn't work at all. I had to change 'button' to 'link' and ':class' to ':text' to even get it to clip one.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
require 'watir-webdriver'

b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => 'default'
b.goto 'https://stopandshop.com/dashboard/coupons-deals/#/coupons-and-deals/exclusive-coupons'

l = b.link :text => '+ load to card' 

sleep 3

l.when_present.click
```

I've tried

```
l.exists?
l.click
```

Which will only work on one instance. I've trued the when_present as shown above. I've even used a while loop to "do" l.click. I've exhausted my resources at this point, as well as my patience. Any help is greatly appreciate. Thank you!

EDIT:

I've found that if I include :index => 1 at the end of the line

```
l = b.link :text => '+ load to card', :index => 1
```

then it will navigate to that specific spot in the array and click that link. So, I guess at this point I need help trying to get it to traverse the array and click all of those links.

EDIT 2: I was hoping to be able to post whether the suggestions worked, however I started running into an issue suddenly where when the site loads, I'm logged in as usual but then suddenly it logs me out for no reason and redirects to

```
https://stopandshop.com/?DPSLogout=true
```

EDIT 3: The Edit 2 issue was fixed. It was a permissions/cookies issue in my browser. However, none of the suggestions are working.

**SOLUTION**

```
while l.exists? do
    l.click
    l = b.link :text => '+ load to card', :index => 0+1
end
```

Comment: Can you show the full code you are using that is working with the :index => 1.

Comment: l = b.link :text => '+ load to card', :index => 1

Comment: If you have a solution to your question that's not included in any of the answers you should answer your own question and mark it as correct. No harm in that

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to iterate through the links like so:

```
coupons = b.links(text: '+ load to card')
coupons.each do |coupon|
  coupon.click
end
```

Comment: Yes, that one should work except you might need a `b.back` inside the loop.

Comment: So, I put this in as is and it's not working at all. I'm not sure why. But before I was able to get at least 1 coupon to clip but now it won't clip any and the script is closing. Am I forgetting something?

Comment: I can't tell what you implemented based on the limited info in your comment.

Comment: Yes, it would be helpful if you pasted the entire bit of code you are working on so we can see the whole thing.